# Create a wireless network in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04, file-sharing

Whenever i need to copy some files and can't find a pen drive, (I don't have Bluetooth enabled in my laptop), I create a new ad hoc (wireless) network in Windows and share the necessary files on the network and share the files with the other system.

Now I want to do the same with Ubuntu, but I can't. I can create a new network, but i am not able to share or send and don't even know how to access the system connected to the network. How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: You could ask this in http://askubuntu.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/ and get better/faster answers

Answer (score 0):

If you have the network setup, and the computers can at least see each other, making them talk is the next step. In order to do this, you can use [Samba](http://www.samba.org/). It is designed to make network sharing between a Windows client and Linux desktop possible.